# How to dynamically order search results in elastic search based on a criteria obtained at runtime?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We have six categories event_rule_1 to event_rule_6, each can have one priority i.e. High, Medium, Low

I want to show search results based on a priority, Where the priority data is present in the database.

Current approach:

I was fetching the priority from the database and applying on the query i.e as a boost

For High I am giving a boost of 3, Medium boost of 2 and Low a boost of 1.

like below

```
 GET /<index_name>/_search
 {
   "from" : 0,
   "size" : 200,
   "query" : {
     "bool" : {
       "must" : [ {
         "term" : {
           "fleet_id" : 1
         }
       }, {
         "exists" : {
           "field" : "result"
         }
       }, {
         "terms" : {
           "state" : [ "active", "viewed" ]
         }
       } ],
       "should" : [ {
         "match" : {
           "alert_code" : {
             "query" : "event_rule_1",
             "type" : "boolean",
             "boost" : 3.0
           }
         }
       }, {
         "match" : {
           "alert_code" : {
             "query" : "event_rule_2",
             "type" : "boolean",
             "boost" : 3.0
           }
         }
       }, {
         "match" : {
           "alert_code" : {
             "query" : "event_rule_3",
             "type" : "boolean",
             "boost" : 3.0
           }
         }
       }, {
         "match" : {
           "alert_code" : {
             "query" : "event_rule_4",
             "type" : "boolean",
             "boost" : 2.0
           }
         }
       }, {
         "match" : {
           "alert_code" : {
             "query" : "event_rule_5",
             "type" : "boolean",
             "boost" : 1.0
           }
         }
       }, {
         "match" : {
           "alert_code" : {
             "query" : "event_rule_6",
             "type" : "boolean",
             "boost" : 1.0
          }
         }
       } ]
     }
   }
 }
```

But this approach does not seem to work, When I tested with different boost values.

Is there something wrong with this approach? Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in elastic search?

ES schema:

Updated json schema

```
 PUT /schema
{
"alert": {
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "alert_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "fleet_id": {
            "type": "long",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "truck_id": {
            "type": "long",
            "index": "no"
        },
        "alert_code": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "alert_desc": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "no"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "no"
        },
        "inspected_by": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "no"
        },
        "unit_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "comment": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "alert_on": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "epoch_millis",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "is_flagged": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "index": "no"
        },
        "make": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "no"
        },
        "model": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "no"
        },
        "year": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "no"
        },
        "axle_config_id": {
            "type": "long",
            "index": "no"
        },
        "state": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "viewed_on": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "epoch_millis",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "flagged_on": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "epoch_millis",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "dismissed_on": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "epoch_millis",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I've just indexed a few test docs and tried out your query, and it works for me (ES 5.1.2, but probably doesn't matter). Can you give a minimal example that doesn't work? (ideally show the put request for creating empty index, and indexing a couple of docs, and show which order you get and explain why it's wrong; also mention your ES version)

Comment: @dshockley have updated the PUT request and ES version is 2.3.3

Comment: Can you add the documents also? A minimal example so we can reproduce your issue, with just a couple of docs. Also I'd remove the unrelated fields from the mapping for the example.

Comment: @dshockley used a functional score query to implement custom ordering.

Answer (score 0):

What was the problem with the results?

Default order by is score, so the boost was a great idea, and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Used a functional score query to implement custom ordering

```
GET /schema_name/_search
{
"from": 0,
"size": 200,
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "boost": "5",
        "functions": [{
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "alert_code": "event_rule_1"
                    }
                },
                "weight": 50
            },
            {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "alert_code": "event_rule_2"
                    }
                },
                "weight": 30
            },
            {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "alert_code": "event_rule_3"
                    }
                },
                "weight": 10
            },
            {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "alert_code": "event_rule_4"
                    }
                },
                "weight": 10
            },
            {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "alert_code": "event_rule_5"
                    }
                },
                "weight": 50
            },
            {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "alert_code": "event_rule_6"
                    }
                },
                "weight": 50
            }
        ],
        "max_boost": 50,
        "score_mode": "max",
        "boost_mode": "replace",
        "min_score": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Weight is added to the functions at run-time depending on the configurations that is saved in the database.

The parameter boost_mode is set to **replace** i.e. ***only function score is used, the query score is ignored.***

PS: Had to choose this approach because changing boost in the query didn't give consistent results as the query results depended not only on boost value but also on several other scores.